# AJAX and PHP code not working

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am sending my form data through AJAX but for some reason my PHP script is not running. The test echo's Im using in my PHP script is not showing. The window.alert("success") does show but HIDE and SHOW form1 and form2 also does not work.

Here is the code:

```
$('#mainform').on('submit', function(event) {
      //test for empty fields
      //test for Bots
      //insert data into DB
      //pass t_code on to next form
      //create a page number for tabs

      event.preventDefault(); //stops form on submit
      var a = document.forms["mainform"]["hidden"].value;
      if (a === ""){
          var formData = {};
          $.each($("#mainform").serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
            formData[field.name] = field.value;
          });
          $.ajax({
          url: 'insert_tut_description.php',
          data: formData,
          method:'POST',
          success: function(response) { 
              window.alert("success");
              pnum = 1;
              t_code = form.elements["t_code"].value;
              $("#form1").hide();
              $("#form2").show();
              document.getElementById("pnum").innerHTML = pnum;
           }
    });
    };
});    


<?php

echo "php running";

require 'config/config.php';

$t_title    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['t_title']);
$t_code     = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['t_code']);
$t_image    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['t_image']);
$hidden     = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['hidden']);
$t_desc     = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['t_desc']);
$t_url      = "something.php";

echo $t_title;
echo t_url;

if(empty($hidden)){
    echo "hidden is empty";
    $query = "INSERT into tutorial_list (title, description, t_code, t_url, image,) VALUES('" . $t_title . "','" . $t_desc . "','" . $t_code . "','" . $t_url . "','" . $t_image . "')";

    $success = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$success) {
        die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
    } else {
        $conn->close();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Instead the windows alert, put console.log(response) and tell me what it shows now

Comment: And always add the error function: 
succes: function(response){
...
},
  error: function(e, t, a) {
             console.log(e)
         }

Comment: php runningHeadert_urlhidden is emptyCouldn't enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES('Header','hello','D_001','something.php','image1')' at line 1
create_tutorial.php?t_title=&t_code=&t_image=&t_desc=&submit=:228 Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined
    at Object.success (create_tutorial.php?t_title=&t_code=&t_image=&t_desc=&submit=:228)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>

Comment: Awesome! what was it?

Comment: Jose - there was a simple syntax problem. An extra comma at the end of my INSERT clause right after 'image'. I also had to refer to the correct form.element name.